# "Is" versus "are"

Tags: grammatical-number

I have a super silly question. I've been living abroad too long and teaching low level ESL has done the BYElingual thing to me.

This sentence **"Reading comic books is bad."** should the "is" be "are" or is that sentence correct? I know plural nouns (books) get plural are, but is the "is" in this case connected to reading? This sentence is from a textbook I'm teaching and it sounds a bit odd to me.

I have a similar confusion with "What is/are Jack and Sally's favourite subject?" I know these sentences are super basic, and I've searched online but couldn't get a specific answer. This is what I think: Jack and Sally become they, therefore "what ARE their favourite subject?" Correct?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Making adult decisions "is" or "are" really not fun: Which is correct?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/18815/making-adult-decisions-is-or-are-really-not-fun-which-is-correct)

Comment: See also [“Doing such stunts ARE punishable”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/397260/doing-), [“Which exams is he taking?” or “Which exams are he taking?”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/460994)

Comment: Why aren't all those posts migrated to [ell.se]?

Comment: Non-finite subject clauses take singular agreement, so "is" would be correct. In your second example, the subject is "Jack and Sally's favourite subject". The head word of the subject is the singular "subject", thus the verb should be the singular "is".

Answer (score 3):

**Look for what the verb should agree with.**

In your first example, the verb is related to "reading":

- **Reading** (something) ***is*** (whatever).

This isn't because *reading* is 'singular', but because *reading* has *singular agreement*.

In your second example, it's the favourite subject:

- What ***is*** (their) **favourite subject**?

If one person had multiple subjects (dropping 'favourite' to avoid any "just one" connotation), agreement is still with *subject*:

- What ***are*** John's **subjects**?

Comment: What is [ell.se] for!

Comment: @Kris Feel free to vote to migrate the question there.