# Do I use "is" or "are" in this sentence?

Tags: grammar

What strategies *is* your school using to the reduce summer melt?
OR
What strategies *are* your school using to the reduce summer melt?

Comment: It is the *school* which is singular. "What is the school doing?" "What are schools doing?"

Comment: See also [“Which exams is he taking?” or “Which exams are he taking?”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/460994)